# pthread_join() for asynchronous threads

Tags: c, multithreading, asynchronous, pthreads, pthread-join

I have written a simple demonstration program so that I can understand the `pthread_join()` function.

I know how to use the `pthread_condition_wait()` function to allow asynchronous threading but I'm trying to understand how I can do similar work using the `pthread_join()` function.

In the program below I pass *Thread 1s* ID to *Thread 2s* function. Inside *Thread 2s* function I call the `pthread_join()` function and pass in *Thread 1s* ID. I expected this to cause *Thread 1* to run first and then for *Thread 2* to run second, but what I'm getting is that they both run concurrently.

Is this because only one thread can use the `pthread_join()` function at a time and that I am already using the `pthread_join()` function when I call it from the *main thread*?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *functionCount1();
void *functionCount2(void*);

int main()
{

    /* 
        How to Compile
         gcc -c foo
         gcc -pthread -o foo foo.o
    */

    printf("\n\n");

    int rc;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    /* Create two thread --I took out error checking for clarity*/
    pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionCount1, NULL)
    pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionCount2, &thread1)

    pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

    printf("\n\n");
    exit(0);
}

void *functionCount1()
{

    printf("\nFunction 1");
        sleep(5);
    printf("\nFunction 1");

    return(NULL);
}

void *functionCount2(void* argument)
{

    pthread_t* threadID = (pthread_t*) argument;

    pthread_join(*threadID, NULL);

    printf("\nFunction 2");
        sleep(5);
    printf("\nFunction 2");

    return(NULL);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When threads are created using `pthread_create()`, both threads start execution concurrently and there's no fixed ordering on their order of execution. The order depends on the OS scheduling and number of processors available etc. In any case, that can't be determined and that's the point of threads anyway.

What happens when you call `pthread_join()`, the caller waits for thread that join with to terminate. So main thread waits for `thread1` to terminate and then for `thread2`. But while main waits for `thread1`, `thread2` might have finished execution and terminated already. In this case, `pthread_join(thread2, NULL);` would return immediately.

You have a bigger problem in your code. You are passing `thread1`'s ID to `thread2`. But if `thread1` finished execution before `thread2` starts, then you are going be using an invalid thread identifier, *leading to undefined behaviour*. Another problem is that your main thread and `thread2` both trying to join with `thread1`. In short, `pthread_join()` is not the right tool for synchronization between multiple threads. As you stated, you be using conditional variable/mutexes for this purpose.

I suggest, you remove `pthread_join()` from `thread2`, to fix undefined behaviour and if you want serial execution of threads, then you have to create threads one after another and let them and wait for the previous thread to terminate (`pthread_join()`). But there's very little practical use in doing this. Or let the threads wait on a conditional variable before doing anything and you can make the threads communicate in the order you desire using conditional variables.

Comment: I think the "root cause" problem is the call of `pthread_join( thread1, NULL);` from the `main()`: it leads to a possibility of concurrent joining, which is undefined. The removal should fix the invalid thread identifier issue, too, because thread1 would remain unjoined until the call from thread2.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's a very valid point. I'll update that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You invoke undefined behavior. the man page:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html

```
Joining with a thread that has previously been joined results in undefined behavior.
```

Also the first thread might finish exectution before the second thread. If you want something like this it is alot better to use `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [pthread_join man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join)(emphasis mine):

> *If multiple threads simultaneously try to join with the same thread, the results are undefined.* If the thread calling pthread_join() is canceled, then the target thread will remain joinable (i.e., it will not be detached).

It seems that you are exactly in this situation, with main thread and thread 2 both trying to `pthread_join` thread 1.

You should clearly define for each thread a single "owner thread " which is responsible for its management. The chain of responsibility should form a hierarchical tree of thread (ie no  cycles or multiple parents).