# Can someone tell me the error as pthread_join is not working

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
struct Array 
{
    //
};
void* evensum(void* param)
{
    //calculated the sum of even elements and returned it
}
void* oddsum(void* param)
{ 
  //did the same thing but for odd elements
}
int main()
{
    struct Array* obj=malloc(sizeof(struct Array));
    //did all the inputs
    int evensum,oddsum; 
    pthread_t thread1,thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread1,0,&evensum,(void*)obj);
    int evensum,oddsum;
    pthread_join(&thread,(void**)evensum);
    pthread_create(&thread2,0,&oddsum,(void*)obj);
    pthread_join(&thread2,(void**)oddsum);
    //try to print it using %i but I get or  %d 
    // I get the sum as zero
}
```

So I created two separate threads and these threads were meant to work asynchronously. I followed the advice mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895245/pthread-join-for-asynchronous-threads)  but the join still doesn't work as once the thread1 finishes execution, the other thread is never created despite me following the correct syntax. Any idea how to fix this?
Also, the value printed is zero, despite showing the correct value if I print it in the function.
Here is what I wrote in  the return statement of each function:

```
return (void*)sum;//variable that stores sum
```

Also, I want to add that I don't want to use semaphores or any other synchronization tool to do this.

Comment: what's your real problem "the other thread is never created " what does it mean? it crashes? it exits? computer catches fire? something else?

Comment: What I meant is that the function meant for the thread is never called, and the terminal just stops after printing the sum of the even elements, which was just after pthread_join(&thread,(void**)evensum). It prints the value 0 and stops right there and the main thread doesn't terminate. Sorry if I confused you cause I had omitted the line for brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `pthread_join` is a `void **`, i.e. it expects a *pointer* to a `void *` which it dereferences to store the value in.  Because you're not passing the address of a variable, this function will attempted to use whatever value you passed in as an address (which would likely be invalid) and dereference it.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, the first parameter is of type `pthread_t` but you're passing a *pointer* to a `pthread_t`.

You're also declaring local variables with the same names as the functions you're calling.  As a result, when you call `pthread_create(&thread2,0,&oddsum,(void*)obj);` you're actually passing the local `int` variable called `oddsum` and not the function called `oddsum`.  That's why it hangs.

Changing the name of the variables to hold the results, changing the `pthread_join` calls to pass the addresses of these variables and passing the thread IDs directly should work:

```
int evenresult;
pthread_join(thread,(void**)&evenresult);
...
int oddresult;
pthread_join(thread2,(void**)&oddresult);
```

The proper way to do retrieve the result however would be to pass the addresses of actual `void *` variables and converting them:

```
int evenresult, oddresult;
void *result;
pthread_join(thread, &result);
evensum = (intptr_t)result;
...
pthread_join(thread2, &result);
oddsum = (intptr_t)result;
```

Comment: `pthread_join(&thread, &result);`   `&thread` typo? Syntax goes `int pthread_join(pthread_t tid, void **ret);`

Comment: @kiranBiradar Yes, I missed that.  Updated.

Comment: That fixed the problem related to threads not terminating. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create all the thread and then join them like below:-

```
pthread_create(&thread1,0,&evensum,(void*)obj);
pthread_create(&thread2,0,&oddsum,(void*)obj);

pthread_join(&thread1,(void**)evensum);
pthread_join(&thread2,(void**)oddsum);
```

Comment: do you care to explain why?

Comment: `pthread_join(&thread1, &result);` `&thread1` typo? Syntax goes `int pthread_join(pthread_t tid, void **ret);`